# Obtaining the size of an array in a Fortran subroutine called from Python using ctypes

Tags: python, arrays, fortran, size, ctypes

How can I write a Python code that calls the following Fortran subroutine via ctypes?
The Fortran code receives an array from the Python code, gets the size of the array, and prints it out.

```
subroutine get_array_size(a)
implicit none

integer, intent(in) :: a(:,:)

print *, size(a, 1), size(a, 2)
end subroutine get_array_size
```

I've searched on the web (as well as asked ChatGPT), but I could not find the answer.

Comment: You probably can't because of the assumed shape `a(:,:)`. That is not interoperable in C in Fortran 2008 and complicated in F2018.

Comment: Basically, without `bind(C)` in the Fortran subroutine you are on your own and have to create a Fortran array descriptor for the specific compiler. With `bind(C)` in Fortran you could create a standard Fortran array descriptor for the numpy array you have in Python using the C header `ISO_Fortran_binding.h`. I am not sure if someone already did that somewhere.

Comment: You'd probably better write a wrapper Fortran routine that receives the size as arguments (hence with an explicit shape declaration), and then call the one with the assumed shaped declaration.

Comment: If all you are doing is finding the dimensions of the array, why don’t you just do it in python? print( numpy.shape( a ) )

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. What I really want to do is to do some work with an array "a" in a Fortran subroutine. For simplicity of the code, I want the Fortran subroutine only to receive the array itself and get the size of the array by SIZE(a) or something.

Comment: If you get the size (or shape) in Python and pass that with the array then you won’t have the problems with assumed shape.

Comment: As stated by @VladimirFГероямслава, it is maybe possible but at least quite complicated. It will be way simpler to explicitely pass the size.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I agree that it is the simplest to pass its size with an array to Fortran.